# Rails / Heroku Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am having troubles running my app on Heroku. The app works fine locally and gives me no errors when I push.

I am a bit of a noob but here are the logs.... what am I doing wrong exactly? A few things, I am sure ;)

Thanks!

```
2014-08-02T02:56:42.476683+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
2014-08-02T02:56:42.476676+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-08-02T02:56:42.476694+00:00 app[web.1]:    script/rails:6:in `require'
2014-08-02T02:56:42.476678+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-08-02T02:56:42.476687+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2014-08-02T02:56:42.476686+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
2014-08-02T02:56:42.476692+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2014-08-02T02:56:42.476724+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-02 02:56:42] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-08-02T02:56:42.476702+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-02 02:56:42] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2014-08-02T02:56:42.476691+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2014-08-02T02:56:45.569017+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
 to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2014-08-02T02:56:45.568550
+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2014-08-02T02:56:46.545364+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:33203
2014-08-02T02:56:46.545366+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2014-08-02T02:56:46.545359+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-08-02T02:56:46.545368+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-08-02T02:56:46.545369+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2014-08-02T02:56:46.732149+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-02 02:56:46] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2014-08-02T02:56:46.732161+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-02 02:56:46] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux]
2014-08-02T02:56:46.732729+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-02 02:56:46] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=33203
2014-08-02T02:56:43.886636+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-08-02T02:56:42.010285+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-08-02T02:56:47.056544+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-08-02T02:56:42.970420+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 33203`
2014-08-02T03:00:05.358113+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by barry.lachapelle@gmail.com
2014-08-02T03:00:09.590408+00:00 heroku[run.9409]: State changed from starting to up
2014-08-02T03:00:13.162415+00:00 heroku[run.9409]: State changed from up to complete
2014-08-02T03:00:09.290473+00:00 heroku[run.9409]: Awaiting client
2014-08-02T03:00:13.152932+00:00 heroku[run.9409]: Process exited with status 0
2014-08-02T03:00:09.342086+00:00 heroku[run.9409]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-08-02T03:00:21.764691+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 106.147.253.226 at 2014-08-02 03:00:21 +0000
2014-08-02T03:00:22.034004+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=ruffbooks.herokuapp.com request_id=dc981a56-9021-454e-930f-e6a3f3715fbd fwd="106.147.253.226" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=279ms status=500 bytes=758
2014-08-02T03:00:22.016420+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#index as HTML
2014-08-02T03:00:22.028108+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.7ms)
2014-08-02T03:00:22.029621+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-02T03:00:22.029623+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (defaults.js isn't precompiled):
2014-08-02T03:00:22.029625+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:   <head>
2014-08-02T03:00:22.029626+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:     <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Untitled" %></title>
2014-08-02T03:00:22.029627+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
2014-08-02T03:00:22.029629+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
2014-08-02T03:00:22.029630+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
2014-08-02T03:00:22.029634+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__347943086722083126_69894744358040'
2014-08-02T03:00:22.028117+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms
2014-08-02T03:00:22.029632+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     <%= yield(:head) %>
2014-08-02T03:00:22.029635+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-02T03:00:22.029637+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-02T03:00:22.029633+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:   </head>
2014-08-02T03:00:22.872918+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ruffbooks.herokuapp.com request_id=06611019-6bda-4c8c-b6a2-6cfc4ce1d2fa fwd="106.147.253.226" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=748
2014-08-02T03:03:57+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-08-02T03:04:09+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-08-02T03:04:09.949182+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2014-08-02T03:04:09.852212+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 1d124f1 by barry.lachapelle@gmail.com
2014-08-02T03:04:09.852373+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v28 created by barry.lachapelle@gmail.com
2014-08-02T03:04:13.359256+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
2014-08-02T03:04:13.359228+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-02 03:04:13] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2014-08-02T03:04:13.359238+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-08-02T03:04:13.359241+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2014
-08-02T03:04:13.359243+00:00 app[web.1]:        /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-08-02T03:04:13.359259+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2014-08-02T03:04:13.359261+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-08-02T03:04:13.359240+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-08-02T03:04:13.359266+00:00 app[web.1]:    script/rails:6:in `require'
2014-08-02T03:04:13.359264+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2014-08-02T03:04:13.359258+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
2014-08-02T03:04:13.359268+00:00 app[web.1]:    script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2014-08-02T03:04:13.359263+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2014-08-02T03:04:13.359453+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-02 03:04:13] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2014-08-02T03:04:13.359573+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-02 03:04:13] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-08-02T03:04:13.359684+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-08-02T03:04:14.853313+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
log.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2014-08-02T03:04:14.852857+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
 to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2014-08-02T03:04:15.736918+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2014-08-02T03:04:15.736904+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-08-02T03:04:15.736921+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2014-08-02T03:04:15.812883+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-02 03:04:15] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux]
2014-08-02T03:04:15.736909+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:29602
2014-08-02T03:04:15.812869+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-02 03:04:15] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2014-08-02T03:04:15.813293+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-02 03:04:15] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=29602
2014-08-02T03:04:15.736920+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-08-02T03:04:16.188320+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-08-02T03:04:12.761970+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-08-02T03:04:14.640636+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-08-02T03:04:12.705585+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 29602`
2014-08-02T03:04:22.615561+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=ruffbooks.herokuapp.com request_id=81868db3-a7e9-4d85-ac67-6ba8f1424167 fwd="106.147.253.226" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=104ms status=500 bytes=758
2014-08-02T03:04:22.611352+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:     <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Untitled" %></title>
2014-08-02T03:04:22.517499+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 106.147.253.226 at 2014-08-02 03:04:22 +0000
2014-08-02T03:04:22.611354+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
2014-08-02T03:04:22.611357+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
2014-08-02T03:04:22.611355+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
2014-08-02T03:04:22.611346+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-02T03:04:22.611359+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     <%= yield(:head) %>
2014-08-02T03:04:22.605983+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.7ms)
2014-08-02T03:04:22.611363+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-02T03:04:22.611360+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:   </head>
2014-08-02T03:04:22.611349+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (defaults.js isn't precompiled):
2014-08-02T03:04:22.611362+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3942217403030960468_70065509394080'
2014-08-02T03:04:22.611351+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:   <head>
2014-08-02T03:04:22.611365+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-02T03:04:22.598270+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#index as HTML
2014-08-02T03:04:22.609526+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms
2014-08-02T03:04:23.455514+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ruffbooks.herokuapp.com request_id=f5d35eda-4dbd-4b4b-9954-27daea69e02c fwd="106.147.253.226" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=748
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` on line 5 of your index.

Comment: This is right. For anyone finding this... Nifty Generators adds deprectaed JS path. This is the fix.

Answer (score 2):

## Errors

To give you some more information regarding running your app on Heroku, there are two types of error you will encounter:

**Heroku**

[image]

**Rails**

[image]

These errors will show when you try and load your Heroku app (`http://***.herokuapp.com`), and are relatively simple to decode.

> - **Rails** errors occur because of your own code (typically you have a syntax error).
> - **Heroku** errors occur because of how you've set up your Heroku environment (IE platform errors)

The difference is that if you have a *Rails* error, your application is running correctly on Heroku -- it just has a lot of internal issues, probably in regards to your syntax. If you see the Heroku error, it essentially means you don't have Heroku's platform setup correctly (typically no `db`), meaning you'll have to work on Heroku to sort it out.

---

**Logs**

The problem you're alluding to is a `Rails` issue, as you can see the details in the logs as to what the error might be. An important note is that *Heroku* errors will typically not report anything in your logs (but that's another story)

I would highly recommend using the [LogEntries add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/logentries):

[image]

Installing this, and then using the "real-time" functionality in the back-end will allow you to better digest the errors you're receiving. At least it helped us

--

**Reading Logs** is an art in itself. Typically, you'll be looking for specific "error" messages - but doing that can be quite difficult. The way I read your logs was as follows:

Upon browsing through your attachment, I found the following line:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (defaults.js isn't precompiled):
```

This *should* be the error (although it might be part of another). It explains that you don't have `defaults.js` in your `app/assets/javascripts/` folder; which `Jade McGough` correctly pointed out, meant that you needed to reference the "application" JS file instead

Comment: Thanks for the much more thorough (and ultimately more useful) answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the following code with line 5:

and run **" heroku run rake assets:precompile "** this command on project path